# Why do I get an endless loop?

Tags: java, debugging

Why does this program create an endless loop after receiving the input `number`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberDrawn = drawNumber();
    int number;
    System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
    number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    while (number != numberDrawn) {
        if(number < numberDrawn) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");
        } else if (number > numberDrawn) {
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
        }
    }

}

private static int drawNumber() {
    return new Random().nextInt(101);
}
```

Comment: Because inside the loop the value of the variables you check for never changes obviously.

Comment: Unless I'm blind, I don't see how `number` is moved inside of the loop.

Comment: Start using debugger and you will be able to track such problems yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Your core code looks like:

```
int numberDrawn = new Random().nextInt(101);
int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
while (number != numberDrawn) {
    ...
}
```

But inside of the loop you do **not change** `numberDrawn` or the users guess for `number`.

So the while-loop executes what is inside (some print statements) and then checks the condition `number != numberDrawn` again. But as the numbers did not change, if they were not equal in the first place, you enter the **next iteration**. This obviously **continues endlessly**.

---

A small example with numbers:

```
int numberDrawn = 3;
int number = 10;
while (number != numberDrawn) {
    ...
}
```

Now `number != numberDrawn` resolves to `3 != 10` which is `true`, so the loop starts and executes the prints:

```
if(number < numberDrawn) {
    System.out.println("The number is greater");
} else if (number > numberDrawn) {
    System.out.println("The number is lesser");
} else {
    System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
}
```

It will print `The number is greater` since `3 < 10`. The iteration ends and `number != numberDrawn` is checked again. As the numbers did not change it resolves to `3 != 10` i.e. `true` again, **continuing endlessly**.

---

### Solution

You probably wanted to **repeat the guessing game** if the numbers were not equal. For this you need to **move** the guessing procedure **inside the loop**, like this:

```
int numberDrawn = drawNumber();
// Initial value which ensures that loop is entered
int number = -1;

while (number != numberDrawn) {
    // Let the user guess a number
    System.out.println("Guess a number!");
    number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    // Check the number
    if(number < numberDrawn) {
        System.out.println("The number is greater");
    } else if (number > numberDrawn) {
        System.out.println("The number is lesser");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
    }
}
```

Now you let the user repeatedly choose new numbers based on the message of the last iteration.

Of course you could also use a `do-while` loop instead of a regular `while`, then you do not need that initial `-1` value for `number`.

Comment: I just want to point out since this is the accepted answer that the last else statement will never be reached because if `number` = `numberDrawn` then the while loop will not execute.

Comment: @user2023608 The while loop will allways execute at least once, because Zabuza initialized number with -1 while numberDrawn=drawNumber() will generate a random positive number. So when first reached the condition will allways be true and the actual guessing of the number only starts inside the loop.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see it now.

Comment: Yeah, this logic may not seem straightforward. You can give it a better structure, for example with a `do-while` loop where the first iteration will always be executed since the condition there will be checked after the iteration instead of before the iteration. But I wanted to stick to OPs structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your printing out the statement that a number is less or greater but not taking any input afterwords so the value of `number` never changes.  Try something like:

```
while (number != numberDrawn) {
    if(number < numberDrawn) {
        System.out.println("The number is greater");
        number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    } else if (number > numberDrawn) {
        System.out.println("The number is lesser");
        number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    } 
}
System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take input after each iteration

```
        number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```